# Use of calendar class

Tags: android

I have created an xml layout which is in effect a grid. I need to use it as a calendar and have read about the calendar class but i've been unable to get any of the code it suggests to work.

How would i go about displaying the current year,month and days in the various text views?

This is what i have so far:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    String month_name = Integer.toString(month);

    TextView monthdisp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.month_disp);

    monthdisp.setText(month_name);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

However a null pointer excpetion is generated at monthdisp.setText(month_name);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the Android Developers guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) To get the current year, month and days you'd use the following:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR); // get the current year
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); // month...
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day in the month

// sets your textview to e.g. 2012/03/15 for today
textview.setText("Year / month / day: "+ year + "/" + month + "/" + day);
```

Alternatively, you can use `SimpleDateFormat` like so:

```
// set-up the desired formatting
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

Date now = cal.getTime(); // set the current datetime in a Date-object

// SimpleDateFormat.format( Date date ) returns a formatted string
// with the predefined format
String mTimeString = sdf.format( now ); // contains yyyy-MM-dd (e.g. 2012-03-15 for March 15, 2012)

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText( mTimeString );
```

The other way around also works:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

String mDateString = "14-05-2012";
Date mDate = sdf.parse( mDateString ); // returns a Date-object
                                       // with date set to May 14, 2012
```

Comment: Im trying the first method you sugested I keep getting null pointer exceptions on this line: monthdisp.setText("Year / month / day: "+ year + "/" + month + "/" + day);

Comment: It looks like monthdisp is null. `.setText( null )` doesn't throw a NullPointer.

Comment: You're trying to get your `TextView` from your layout, before you're actually inflating your layout. This means that your TextView does not exist yet in the layout. 

Move `setContentView(R.layout.main);` to the top and it should work fine. Put it just below the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.

Comment: ahh i understand now, thank you that worked, I've read the documentation and see the get(Calendar.MONTH) returns an integer is there a way i can display the month as a word?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the method Calendar.getDisplayName() at [the developer's guide for Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html). Or again, you can use SimpleDateFormat for this.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here provide good info about the Calendar class and date/time manipulation, but that's not why your code is throwing a NullPointerException:

```
TextView monthdisp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.month_disp);

monthdisp.setText(month_name); // NPE here indicates monthdisp is null
```

Calling `findViewById(R.id.month_disp)` returned `null`. This is probably because you haven't inflated your view yet, or `month_disp` just isn't in your layout.

Typically, view inflation occurs in the [Activity.onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) method, and you can do it in several ways, for instance [setContentView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29). Check that you are doing this *before* calling `findViewById()`, and that the layout you are inflating actually has that view in it.